# Почему в операторе delete не выполнена операция обнуливания указателя?

Tags: c++

Допустим у меня есть понятие:

```
class Predator;
class Animal{ public: Predator* confirmation; ...}
// тут производные классы, представляющие разные животные
//теперь преобразование хищникa 
void  transform(Animal* P) {
    if(P) delete P->confirmation; // удалили обьект, но это еще хищник
    P = 0;  // уже не хищник
}
```

Вопрос: если обнуливание указателья сразу реализовалось бы в операторе  `delete`, то какого  рода программы пострадали бы от этого?
P.S. я хотел обнулять  `P->confirmation` , а не `P = 0`;  и указатель нужно было передать в функцию не по значению. Но после ответа не корректно... (ошибка невнимательности)

Comment: Возможно, Вам нужно узнать об умных указателях - они как раз все это и реализуют

Comment: о них я знаю. но  вопрос не  об этом

Comment: Harry конечно почти все правильно написал, но краткий ответ такой, если бы delete и мог занулить указатель, то ему пришлось бы отслеживать все остальные указатели и корректно их обнулять. А это приводит к GC или умным указателям.

Comment: @ KoVadim, да, я согласен, что ваш ответ является кратким и ясным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы обнуляете - никакого эффекта вне вашей функции `transform` не имеет. Ваше `P = 0` скорее всего компилятор просто выбросит. Потому что вы работаете с *копией*, локальной для данной функции.

Оператор `delete` получает не ссылку, а значение указателя. Так что вы можете работать с выражениями-указателями, а не только с переменными. А вот если бы он обнулял - то вы были бы обязаны передавать только переменную.

И, кстати, сильно бы это спасало в ситуации, например,

```
Type * p = new Type;
Type * s = p;
delete p;
if (s) s->doIt();
```

?

Comment: ну да, я забыл передать ссыльку на указатель в transform

Comment: ответ убедительный, но  поймет ли это широкая публика? Хотелось бы...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan: Поймёт, у нас умная публика. :)